# receive pictures and text from web service?

Tags: android, web-services, architecture

Is it possible to receive multiple pictures and text from a web service method?
Or multiple web service calls is needed?

for example from an android device I would like to get student data that might contains:

```
    driver license scan (image) 
    driver license expiration date  (date)
    driver license Issue location (string)
    student card scan (Image)
    student card expiration date  (date)
```

can I get all this information in one shot i.e.
    ? getStudentInfo()

Or do I need separate calls for each image and the rest of the information?

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can get... Just make an object of the following things and then get a single object... And den you can extract the required information by doing object.information(example)

Answer (score -1):

You can get all of the data you want in one Shot. You can send the response as JSON and have then parsed in android a json parser